# Uncaught ReferenceError & Unexpected Token Error

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension

I am converting [amazon link localizer](https://github.com/wp-plugins/amazon-affiliate-link-localizer) into a Chrome extension.
The error I am currently dealing with is:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: checkAmazonLinks is not defined

The URL that is posting this JSON is: https://freegeoip.net/json/?callback=checkAmazonLinks
I am calling it in my JS file as such:

```
function findLocation() {
if (typeof google != "undefined" && google.loader.ClientLocation != null) {
    var strCountry = google.loader.ClientLocation.address.country_code;
    checkAmazonLinks(strCountry)
    console.log(strCountry)
} else {
    objScript = document.createElement("script");
    objScript.src = "https://freegeoip.net/json/?callback=checkAmazonLinks";
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(objScript);
}
```

Here is my manifest.js:

```
{
"name"              : "amazon linker",
"version"           : "0.1",
"manifest_version"  : 2,
"description"       : "A simple extension that turns all Amazon links on a page into localized affiliate links",
"permissions"     : [ "http://*/*","https://*/*"],
"browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Amazon Linker"
},
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://google.com; https://freegeoip.net;  object-src 'self'",

"content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["amazon-localiser.js"]
    }
],
 "web_accessible_resources": ["amazon-localiser.js","amazon-localiser.php"]
}
```

I have tried removing the callback from the json request at freegeoip, but then I get an error saying

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

There is a function in my .js that calls `checkAmazonLinks()`, which is loaded after `findLocation()`, I have tried rearranging the order, but that did not help. The thinking was to have `checkAmazonLinks()` defined in the .js before `findLocation()` retrieves the JSON via the callback with the same function name.  How do I get past this error?

Comment: Where is the `findLocation` function run from (background page, content script, popup) ?

Comment: It is in the content script, amazon-localiser.js

Answer (score 0):

Content scripts run in an ***[isolated world](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#execution-environment)*** (sandboxed environment). You have defined the **checkAmazonLinks** function in the context of your content script, but `https://freegeoip.net/json/?callback=checkAmazonLinks` is injected and executed in the JS context of the web-page (since content scripts and web-pages share the DOM).
The problem is that in the context of the web-page, there is no `checkAmazonLinks` function defined.

**Solutions:**

**A.)**
Inject the `checkAmazonLinks` function into the web-page as well, before making the request to `https://freegeoip.net/...`. E.g.:

```
...
} else {
    objScript1 = document.createElement("script");
    objScript1.innerHTML = "function checkAmazonLinks(...) {...}";
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(objScript1);

    objScript = document.createElement("script");
    objScript.src = "https://freegeoip.net/json/?callback=checkAmazonLinks";
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(objScript);
}
```

**B.)**
Make (and process) the request in the context of the content script. E.g. making an AJAX call to `https://freegeoip.net/json` and passing the response to the `checkAmazonLinks` function.

Comment: I have been trying A with no luck. I am getting a Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL chrome-extension://infofeofeimlchhlggjgcccdpnpabgbk/amazon-localiser.js:118 error, here is line 118:    objScript1.innerHTML = 'function checkAmazonLinks(strCountry) {....

Comment: How do you expect me to guess what might be the issue if I don't (at the very least) see the whole "line 118" ? :)

Comment: That was whole line 118.

Comment: So, your function definition is `function checkAmazonLinks(strCountry) {...` ? And you wonder what the problem might be ?

Comment: Well, the function continues, I added ..., do you want to see the whole function?

Comment: @BenjaminBakhshi: Based on that code, I don't see any attempt to implement solution (A). You never inject `checkAmazonLinks` into the web-page's context. Besides, I don't see line 118 to correspond to what you mention above.